# Files in TFS not showing up in solution explorer

Tags: file, version-control

I've got files in TFS that are not showing in the solution explorer of VS 2010.  Another developer committed the files to TFS.  I can see the files in TFS, and they are even being copied to my local directory, but they aren't appearing in the solution explorer.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, when my coworker committed his changes, it is marked as changeset 99.  When I look at the hierarchy of the main branch (where he committed the changes to), it says the latest version is changeset 9 (which is the changeset that created that branch).  Why does the hierarchy view say its latest changeset is 9 when clearly the latest changeset is 99? Am I using the tools incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 'known' bug in VS/TFS. If you checkout a file from the 'Solution Items', VS goes and removes the file from the project.

Comment: Do I just re-add the files to the project? And do you have some more information that I could read up on to avoid this in the future?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, or undo the checkout on the solution file. Happens every time I want to edit some Word doc in the solution.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "checkout a file from the 'Solutions Items'"? And are you saying this happens when you checkout the "Solution <Project Name>" file? Thanks

Comment: No, when you checkout a file from 'Solution Items', VS modifies the solution files (ie removes the file). To do this VS need to checkout the solution (.sln) file too.

Answer (score 2):

To show files on the solution explorer you have to add files to the TFS and you have to update your project files also. You can try Show all files button on solution explorer.

For changeset number issue - pres Ctrl+G on the Source Control Explorer. Enter number 99 or click Find for more search options. [Check changeset details or track changeset](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vn7hsiuO8b4). Maybe you are checking wrong project collection or it is a bug.

Comment: Solution explorer show you all project files and project files content. If you add some file into the TFS without adding this file into the project file, this file is not visible on Solution explorer. It is visible on Source Control Explorer only.